# Unable to execute selenium tests on chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

**Local:-**

I am trying to run selenium tests on chrome browser.

Currently, another chrome browser is running and then running a test on chrome browser by opening new profile and getting the following error:-

```
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
    Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a4f1289f17e8ecd38bc67e137c2a12e34a', time: '2015-10-07 09:50:14'
    System info: host: 'lima', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-97-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
    Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
    at 
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:19247 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a4f1289f17e8ecd38bc67e137c2a12e34a', time: '2015-10-07 09:50:14'
System info: host: 'test', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-97-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:19247 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 56 more
```

**Chrome driver configuration:-**

```
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver");
        setPermissiontoFile(resource);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toString());       
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
```

If I close the existing running chrome browser and then I run the selenium tests on chrome browser ,it works.

**Jenkins:-**

When I try to running on jenkins. I am getting the following error:-

```
Exception org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException

Message: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a4f1289f17e8ecd38bc67e137c2a12e34a', time: '2015-10-07 09:50:14' System info: host: 'jenkins, ip: '10.62.1.24', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85' Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

Stacktrace:

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:178)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:27419 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a4f1289f17e8ecd38bc67e137c2a12e34a', time: '2015-10-07 09:50:14'
System info: host: 'jenkins-sandbox.qa.us-west-2.aws.vrv', ip: '10.62.1.24', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_85'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:620)
... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:27419 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
... 43 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
... 56 more
```

What is the problem here, Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Most likely the 2nd chrome process is not opening the socket you expect it to open and selenium is trying to connect to the first process.

Comment: You need to kill chromedriver exe process by running 'taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f ' command before starting your script or after script. Are you using driver.quit or driver.close ?

Comment: @ShekharSwami I am trying to run on jenkins. Getting the error. I have updated my comments.

Comment: Try using java api Runtime.getRuntime().exec("'taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f"); in your script

Comment: @ShekharSwami Its says " Cannot run program "'taskkill": error=2, No such file or directory". FYI chrome is not installed in jenkins. then why am not able to run on jenkins. browser will run in background on jenkins.

Comment: Did you got any solution here? I am also facing the similar issue and have opened a new question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362831/jenkinsdockergrid-execution-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-n

Comment: @RISHIKHANNA Refer my answer. selenium-java and chrome browser version should be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able run selenium tests on chrome browser with already existing chrome browser running. I did upgrading selenium-java from 2.48.0 to 2.48.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.48.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Refer here https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1123