# Jenkins+Docker+Grid Execution - UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, jenkins-docker

While executing my suite dynamically on grid using Docker-compose through Jenkins, I am getting the following **exception stacktrace**:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities firefox
INFO: Using `new FirefoxOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.firefox()`
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '49d4c6ec544d', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.25-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at WebdriverBase.GridDriverManager.setDriver(GridDriverManager.java:144)
    at WebdriverBase.GridDriverManager.getDriver(GridDriverManager.java:115)
    at stepdefinition.PurchaseWorkflow.init(PurchaseWorkflow.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

**My docker-compose.yml file:**
[image]

**My Hub URL** : "http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub"

When executing the same code on local system everything is working fine on Docker container. Problem arises only when I trigger my test from Jenkins.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan any suggestion here is really appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old thread but hoping to help anyone out here, not an exact answer as I am just using the standalone browser of selenium but I have the

> http://service-name:4444/wd/hub

working in my file.

> ```
> await new Builder()
> .setChromeOptions(options)
> .forBrowser("chrome")
> .usingServer("http://selenium:4444/wd/hub/")
> .build();
> ```

Make sure in your docker-compose.yaml file to also use a link in the other service. for example

> ```
> services:   
>     web:
>
>         build:
>             context: ./web
>         links:
>             - selenium
>         ports:
>             - "443:443"
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Try witch shm_size: 2gb in volumes

Comment: Actually there was 2 issues- 1) Have to use Options class instead of desired capabilities class and 2) When executed from Jenkins image, Hub IP address needs to be my network IP, localhost won't work.